# Which method should I use to clean text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I change some text in text area and then by clicking button it's cleaning normally. But the problem is when I want to add new data to text area it will not work and text area is empty.

Which method should I use?

```
$(".button10").on('click', function reset() {    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:RestApi,
        success:function(data3){
            var str = JSON.stringify(data3, undefined, 4);
            $("#myTextArea").html(str);
        },
    });
});

$(".button9").on('click', function reset() {
    $('#myTextArea').val('');
});
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `.val()` like when you're cleaning the textarea instead of `.html()` after your ajax call ?

Comment: did you try   $('#myTextArea').val(null);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This,

```
$(".button10").on('click', function reset() {

$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url:RestApi,
success:function(str){
  $("#myTextArea").val(str);
},
```

});

});

```
$(".button9").on('click', function reset() {
    $('#myTextArea').val('');

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `$('textarea').val('');`

The problem with using  `$('textarea').text('')` , or  `$('textarea').html('')` for that matter is that it will only erase what was in the original DOM sent by the server. If a user clears it and then enters new input, the clear button will no longer work. Using .val('') handles the user input case properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
$(".button10").on('click', function reset() {

$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
    url:RestApi,
    success:function(data3){
    var str = JSON.stringify(data3, undefined, 4);
     $("#myTextArea").val(str);
      },
 });

});


$(".button9").on('click', function reset() {
        $('#myTextArea').val('');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `append` in your ajax success function if you want to keep the text currently in your textarea. Using `html` or `val` will replace all text with the text passed as parameter:

```
$("#myTextArea").append(str);
```

If you want to clear and replace the text in your textarea use `val` instead of `html` (cf answer from @Rushil Pachchigar):

```
$("#myTextArea").val(str);
```